# How do I associate 'user data' with an lxml.etree.Element?

Tags: python, lxml

I'm currently 'porting' some Python code from DOM to `lxml.etree` and I've come across an obstacle: the DOM code in question uses the `Node.setUserData()` and `Node.getUserData` APIs, but I cannot find anything analogous in the lxml API documentation.

In a last-ditch effort, I tried monkey-patching the `lxml.etree.Element` object, but this raises an `AttributeError`:

```
    setattr(element, '_userdata', {})
AttributeError: 'lxml.etree._Element' object has no attribute '_userdata'
```

Am I missing something here, or am I stuck restructuring the code to handle the 'user data' in an entirely different way?

Comment: How do you want the userdata to be represented in XML? As attributes of the element?

Comment: Neither.  The thing about DOM userdata is that it doesn't serialize, so you can put there that you need only while processing the document.

Comment: What are `Node.setUserData()` and `Node.getUserData()` actually used for? These methods are part of DOM Level 3 and they are implemented in minidom, but I cannot find any documentation (https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.dom.html#node-objects).

Comment: “Neither”: well if you want the output in XML you have to figure out how userdata maps to XML, or...it won’t.

Comment: I don't want the output in the XML---that is the whole point of DOM userData.  It enables you to tag nodes with arbitrary data that you can use while processing the document *only*, and that data doesn't appear in the output.  There doesn't appear to be any way to do this with `lxml.etree`.  But, I just tried standard `xml.etree` and I was able to monkey-patch the `Element` successfully.

Comment: What? Sorry in that case I don’t understand what you are trying to achieve by using lxml.etree. Smells like an X-Y question. Lxml is about doing “what it says on the can”, i.e. parsing and generating xml. What is the *actual problem* that you are trying to solve?